# Chimera Token not getting detected in apache

Tags: security-review, chimera-security-scanner

I have uploaded the token, and it is accessible via
http://ksinkar.edubrite.us/ChimeraToken.txt

But somehow Chimera scanner is not finding it, can you please assist whats wrong here?

This is the message we see:

> Unfortunately, we were unable to verify your ownership of the target site. Because of this, your target was not scanned. Chimera may only be used to scan web applications that you own and develop.
>
> Please login to Chimera and download your abuse prevention token and upload it to the root of the target site, following the directions on the token download page. If you continue to have problems, please contact us. You may also run a manual ZAP scan against your target and utilize those results.

Comment: How did you solve this issue